# How to create image from java applet visual output?

Tags: java, image, applet, image-recognition

Is there anyway to create an image from the visual output of a java applet?
Alternatively, an array of rgb values would suffice.

It needs to be similar to Java Robot class' "createScreenCapture(Rectangle screenRect)" except it needs to work even when the applet is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply save the buffer with ImageIO.write(...);

You are using a buffer right?

if you post the source ill write a saveOutput() method for you